# Is there a way to automatically make "Available" in Omni Channel when the user (agent) signs into Salesforce?

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, omnichannel, utility-bar

Ironically, Salesforce asks if you want to log into Omni-Channel when I log into my app. However, when I click the Utility Bar, it still shows offline and sometimes says "Log in to Omni Channel failed". Still, I manually set it to "Available", and it works. Is there a way to automatically log a user/agent into Omni-Channel when they log into Salesforce?

We don't want to rely on the users to set this themselves.

[image: Omni Channel message]

[image: Utility Bar]

Comment: I don't think this feature is currently available (https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYSuUAN/auto-login-to-omni-channel)

Comment: Thanks, Vinay, That would be the accepted answer. I was looking for any way including Apex, but it appears some overzealous folks want to downthumb this question.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently auto login to omni channel feature is unavailable.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYSuUAN/auto-login-to-omni-channel), however found this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005bipQAA) which you might want to look and see if that can help you.